# Publishing Custom Vision Azure in Website

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-custom-vision

I made a image classification using custom vision and published it. After that I got this publishing url and prediction key. Now I am literally confused how to use this as a api in a website that I am making using MERN.

Also the prediction url doesnt work- "{"error":{"code":"404","message": "Resource not found"}}"

This is the ouput details after publishing:

If you have an image URL:

- https://assam-prediction.cognitiveservices.azure.com/customvision/v3.0/Prediction/**2/classify/iterations/TradiitionalVsWestern/url
- Set Prediction-Key Header to : ***
- Set Content-Type Header to : application/json
- Set Body to : {"Url": "https://example.com/image.png"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced the same thing in my environment. When you are request via GET method you will get a 404 error for predication. You can use prediction call by using the POST method as per [**MS document**](https://southcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/Custom_Vision_Prediction_3.0/operations/5c82db60bf6a2b11a8247c15)

[image: Ref1]

To resolve the above use **POST method** and follow the steps.
You can use both image and Image URL.

**Syntax of my prediction URL**

```
https://democustv-prediction.cognitiveservices.azure.com/customvision/v3.0/Prediction/ecsxx /classify/iterations/Iteration1/image
```

**Select your image down here**

[image: Ref2]

Now everting is working fine **200 OK**.

[image: Ref4]